# How to simulate presence of webcam in HTML5?

Tags: javascript, angular, html, typescript, html5-video

I am developing an angular 7 app which takes photos from phone cameras or webcam on a computer. But one of my working machines does not have a webcam. 
Thus, I would like to simulate the presence of a camera.

Ideally, I would like to simulate it from a video file, or a list of image files, or a single image, or an empty fake image in last resort.

I am already using WebcamModule from 'ngx-webcam' but it is not mandatory.

The actual HTML code looks like this :

```html
<!-- in component.html -->
  <webcam [height]="500" [width]="500" [trigger]="triggerObservable" (imageCapture)="handleImage($event)"
    *ngIf="showWebcam" [allowCameraSwitch]="allowCameraSwitch" [switchCamera]="nextWebcamObservable"
    [videoOptions]="videoOptions" (cameraSwitched)="cameraWasSwitched($event)" (initError)="handleInitError($event)">
  </webcam>
  <br />

  <button mat-icon-button (click)="triggerSnapshot();">
    <mat-icon>camera</mat-icon>
  </button>
  <button mat-icon-button (click)="showNextWebcam(true);">
    <mat-icon>switch_camera</mat-icon>
  </button>
```

and is based on https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-webcam-demo

:)

Comment: This isn't a code solution - but one alternative could be to use some kind of streaming/video capture software and by"simulating" a webcam through a plugin, that way you'll deal with less code overhead. https://obsproject.com/forum/resources/obs-virtualcam.539/

Comment: I undestand the idea and advantages, but providing a full intrinsic solution would allows for unit tests, and beside would be independent of the OS.

Comment: For the moment, and in the same idea of @nullptr.t, I'm using https://github.com/jremmons/pyfakewebcam based on video4linux2. It allows to generates arbitrary cameras (/dev/video0, /dev/video1, ...) with python generated streams.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the moment, and in the same idea of @nullptr.t, I'm using github.com/jremmons/pyfakewebcam based on video4linux2. It allows to generates arbitrary cameras (/dev/video0, /dev/video1, ...) with python generated streams.